# Why do i get a SQL error only when page reloads?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, bulma

When I first open the page everything looks good.  The lakes dropdown will auto fill the docks dropdown.  Like so.

[image: Good image]

But if for some reason , I hit submit button with out all the info filled out, it will give me a error and lakes no longer autofills docks drop down. looks like this

[image: good image]

sql error points to this, but no idea what i am doing wrong.

```
 $lakelist=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM lakes ORDER BY lake ASC");
```

here is the full php code for that page.

```
    <?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

 //Include config file
require_once "config.php";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Wake Up Rentals | Jetski Rental</title>

        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />

        <link rel="canonical" href="/" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bsite/assets/app.css" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="/bsite/assets/javascript/crlist.js"> </script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {


            initCs("");
        });
        </script>
    </head>

            <?php

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$lake = $days = $dock = $date = $numberofsports = $numberofdeluxe = $smallTube = $largeTube = $wakeboard= "";
$lake_err = $days_err = $date_err = $numberofsports_err = $numberofdeluxe_err =$smallTube_err = $largeTube_err = $wakeboard_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){



        //Validate lake
        if(empty (trim ($_POST["lake"]))){
            $lake_err = "Please select a lake";
        }else{
            $lake = trim($_POST["lake"]);
        } 

        //Validate days
        if(empty (trim ($_POST["days"]))){
            $days_err = "Please select number of days";
        }else{
            $days = trim($_POST["days"]);
        } 

        //Validate date
        if(empty (trim ($_POST["date"]))){
            $date_err = "Please select a start date";
        }else{
            $date = trim($_POST["date"]);
        } 

        //Validate number of sports
     if (!in_array(trim($_POST["numberofsports"]), ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"])) {
            $numberofsports_err = "Please select an amount";
        }else{
            $numberofsports = trim($_POST["numberofsports"]);
        }


        //Validate nmber of deluxe
             if (!in_array(trim($_POST["numberofdeluxe"]), ["0", "1", "2"])) {
            $numberofdeluxe_err = "Please select an amount";
        }else{
            $numberofdeluxe = trim($_POST["numberofdeluxe"]);
        }

//add info here for the check boxes.
if ( !isset( $_POST[ "smallTube" ] ) ) {
    $smallTube = "no";
} else {
    $smallTube = "yes";
}

//add info here for the check boxes.
if ( !isset( $_POST[ "largeTube" ] ) ) {
    $largeTube = "no";
} else {
    $largeTube = "yes";
}

//add info here for the check boxes.
if ( !isset( $_POST[ "wakeboard" ] ) ) {
    $wakeboard = "no";
} else {
    $wakeboard = "yes";
}

        //dock
                //Validate dock
        if(empty (trim ($_POST["ndock"]))){
            $dock_err = "Please select number of days";
        }else{
            $dock = trim($_POST["ndock"]);
        } 

    if(empty($lake_err) && empty($days_err) && empty($date_err) && empty($numberofsports_err) && empty($numberofdeluxe_err) ){

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO prerental (email, firstname, lastname, address, phonenumber,lake,days,date,numberofsports,numberofdeluxe,smalltube,largetube,wakeboard,dock) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssssssssssss", $param_email,  $param_firstname, $param_lastname, $param_address, $param_phonenumber, $param_lake, $param_days, $param_date, $param_numberofsports, $param_numberofdeluxe, $param_smalltube, $param_largeTube, $param_wakeboard, $param_dock);

            // Set parameters
            $param_email = $_SESSION["email"];
            $param_firstname = $_SESSION["fname"];
            $param_lastname = $_SESSION["lname"];
            $param_address = $_SESSION["address"];
            $param_phonenumber = $_SESSION["phone"];
            $param_lake = $lake;
            $param_days = $days;
            $param_date = $date;
            $param_numberofsports = $numberofsports;
            $param_numberofdeluxe = $numberofdeluxe;
            $param_smalltube = $smallTube;
            $param_largeTube = $largeTube;
            $param_wakeboard = $wakeboard;
            $param_dock = $dock;


            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: FinalChecks.php");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
                    <div class="navbar-brand">
                        <a class="navbar-item c-logo" href="/">
                            <img src="/bsite/assets/images/logo.png" alt="Wake Up Rentals">
                            <span class="e-wakeup">Wake Up</span> <span class="e-rentals">Rentals</span>
                        </a>

                        <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navMenu">
                            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navMenu" class="navbar-menu">
                        <div class="navbar-end">
                            <a href="/why-us" class="navbar-item">Why Wake Up?</a>
                            <a href="/rentals.php" class="navbar-item">Our Rentals</a>
                            <a href="/lakes.php" class="navbar-item">Locations</a>
                            <a href="/book.php" class="navbar-item">Book Now</a>
                            <a href="/contact" class="navbar-item">Contact</a>
                            <a href="/login.php" class="navbar-item">Login</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>

        <section class="section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="columns">
                    <div class="column">
                        <h1>Hi, <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["fname"]); ?></b>. Your ready to order.</h1>
                        <p>
                        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["fname"]); ?><br>
                        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["lname"]); ?><br>
                        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["email"]); ?><br>
                        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["address"]); ?><br>
                        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["phone"]); ?><br>
                        </p>    
                        <p>
                         <a href="sign-uplakenotify.php" class="button is-success">Sign up for lake notification</a>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <a href="sign-upDiscount.php" class="button is-success">Sign up for Discounts</a>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <a href="reset-password.php" class="button is-danger">Reset Your Password</a>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <a href="Logout.php" class="button is-danger">Sign Out of Your Account</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column">
                        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post"> 
                            <label><b>Get your instint quote here!</b></label>

                                <p class = "help is-danger"><?php echo $lake_err; ?></p>

                                <?php //Drop down example
                                    $lakelist=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM lakes ORDER BY lake ASC");
                                        echo"<div class='field'>";
                                        echo"<div class='control'>";
                                        echo"<label class='label'>  Which lake do you want to go to?</label>";
                                        echo"<div class='select'>";
                                        echo "<select name='lake' id='lake' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\" title='lake you want'><option value='0'>Select Lake</option>";
                                        while($clist=mysqli_fetch_array($lakelist))
                                        {
                                          echo "<option value='$clist[lake]'>$clist[lake]</option>"."<br/>";
                                        }
                                        echo"</select>";
                                    mysqli_close($link);
                                 ?>
                                 </div>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="field">
                                 <div class="control">
                                 <label class="label">Select Dock</label>
                                     <div class="select">
                                        <select name="ndock" id="ndock"></select>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>

                             <div class="field">
                                 <div class="control">
                                    <label class="label">How many days would you like?</label>
                                     <div class="select">

                                        <select name="days">
                                            <option value="">Select...</option>
                                            <option value="1">1 Day </option>
                                            <option value="2">2 Day </option>
                                            <option value="3">3 Day </option>
                                            <option value="Week">1 week </option>
                                        </select>
                                        <p class = "help is-danger"><?php echo $days_err; ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="field">
                                <div class="control">
                                <label class="label">What day would you like to start the rental on [Month/day/year]?</label>
                                    <input width="50%" type="text" name="date">
                                    <p class = "help is-danger"><?php echo $date_err; ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="field">
                                <div class="control">
                                <label class="label">Number of sport jet skis to rent?</label>
                                    <div class="select">

                                        <select class="select" name="numberofsports">
                                            <option value="0">0 </option>
                                            <option value="1">1 </option>
                                            <option value="2">2 </option>
                                            <option value="3">3 </option>
                                            <option value="4">4 </option>
                                        </select>
                                        <p class = "help is-danger"><?php echo $numberofsports_err; ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="field">
                                <div class="control">
                                <label class="label">Number of Deluxe jet skis to rent?</label>
                                    <div class="select">

                                        <select class="form-control" name="numberofdeluxe">
                                            <option value="0">0 </option>
                                            <option value="1">1 </option>
                                            <option value="2">2 </option>
                                        </select>
                                        <p class = "help is-danger"><?php echo $numberofdeluxe_err; ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="field">
                                <div class="control">
                                    <label class="checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="smallTube" value="yes"/>Small Tube<br>
                                    </label>
                                    <p class = "help is-danger"><?php echo $smallTube_err; ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="field">
                                <div class="control">
                                    <label class="checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="largeTube" value="yes">Large Tube<br>
                                    </label>
                                    <p class = "help is-danger"><?php echo $largeTube_err; ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="field">
                                <div class="control">
                                    <label class="checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="wakeboard" value="yes">WakeBoard<br>
                                    </label>
                                    <p class = "help is-danger"><?php echo $wakeboard_err; ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field is-grouped is-grouped-centered">
                                <div class="control">
                                    <button class="button is-primary">Get Online Quote</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control">
                                    <button type="reset" class="button is-danger">Reset</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="column">
                        <h2><b>Lake Notifacation</b></h2>
                        <p> You can select to get emails when we are at your lake of choice! When we are at your 
                        lake of choice you can rent Jet Skis by the hour. Only 60$ per hour. Sign up now by clicking on 
                        "Sign up for lake notification".  You can turn this feature on or off at anytime.</p>

                        <h2><b>Sign up for Discounts</b></h2>
                        <p>You can get really good discounts by signing up for discounts. It will make sure when ever a 
                        discount is aviable , you recive it!  We will not send spam, only good discounts for Jet Ski rentals!
                        Sign up now!</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="columns">
                    <div class="column">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="facebook">Facebook</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/privacy-policy">Privacy policy</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column">
                        <h4>Wake Up Rentals</h4>
                        <p>Address</p>
                        <p><a href="tel:+18005596580">+1800 559 6580</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="columns">
                    <div class="column e-copyright">Copyright &copy; 2018, Jet Skies R US</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/bsite/assets/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please note this works till the page reloads, so that is what i am asking help for.  other question says it worked on local but not on server.  In that case something bigger has changed. where mine is just when page reloads.

Comment: You're closing the connection with `mysqli_close($link);` - it's called if the form has been submitted, but it's outside the check to see if the submit was successful. You just need to put it immediately after the `msysqli_stmt_close($stmt);` line

Comment: @andrewsi You mean `mysqli_stmt_close` ;) bit of a typo `msysqli_stmt_close`.

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the connection with mysqli_close($link); - it's called if the form has been submitted, but it's outside the check to see if the submit was successful. You just need to put it immediately after the msysqli_stmt_close($stmt);